# Unable to Sync to S3 with s3cmd

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, ubuntu-12.04, s3cmd

After setting up s3cmd and my S3 bucket, when I try this command

```
sudo s3cmd sync --recursive --preserve /srv s3://MyS3Bucket
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: S3 error: 400 (InvalidRequest): The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
```

My s3cmd version is 1.0.0 which is installed by default after following their "deb" installation guide for by Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

These days, it is recommended to use the **[AWS Command-Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)** (CLI), which also provides a [`sync` capability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html).

Comment: I'm using S3CMD 1.5.2 and sync requests works fine in isoltaition. Nonw I tried to create a .sh script and run it through cron. The cron runs as desired but the script throw an error: 400 (InvalidRequest): Authorization Error. Here is my .sh script: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unable-to-sync-to-s3-with-s3cmd?answer=22612

Answer (score 0):

s3cmd version 1.5.2 is necessary for working with regions such as eu-central-1 (Frankfurt) or cn-north-1 (Bejing).  debs for such are available in Debian experimental and unstable, and Ubuntu Wily universe.  Or you can install from source from https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd.